# Why does \IntlDateFormatter's format differ from \DateTime->format() on given timezone?

Tags: php, timezone, intldateformatter

I am trying to fix a timezone issue in a PHP 8.2 web application. Any date before `1940-02-25` has a one-day difference when comparing the production server (Debian 12) to my local development machine (Fedora 38). Both machines have PHP 8.2, the "Olson" Timezone Database version `2023.3` and PHP's timezone set to `'Europe/Amsterdam'`. But the production server behaves differently.

Below is a straight forward example of three dates: one before, one on and one after the 1940-02-25. I know there was a timezone-related event in Great Britain, but why should that affect the Amterdam timezone?

Curious: if I alter the timezone to `'Europe/London'`, both systems behave the same.

For comparison, I added a `\DateTime->format()` for each date, too. They are correct on both systems.

```php
$locale = 'nl_NL';
$tz = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam');
$dtfmt = new \IntlDateFormatter(
    $locale, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    $tz, \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, "E dd-MM-y"
);

$dt = new \DateTime('1940-02-24', $tz);
print '1940-02-24 => '. $dt->format('   d-m-Y').PHP_EOL;
print '1940-02-24 => '. $dtfmt->format($dt).PHP_EOL;
print PHP_EOL;

$dt = new \DateTime('1940-02-25', $tz);
print '1940-02-25 => '. $dt->format('   d-m-Y').PHP_EOL;
print '1940-02-25 => '. $dtfmt->format($dt).PHP_EOL;
print PHP_EOL;

$dt = new \DateTime('1940-02-26', $tz);
print '1940-02-26 => '. $dt->format('   d-m-Y').PHP_EOL;
print '1940-02-26 => '. $dtfmt->format($dt).PHP_EOL;
print PHP_EOL;
```

Expected output (and actual output on my local machine):

```
1940-02-24 =>    24-02-1940
1940-02-24 => za 24-02-1940

1940-02-25 =>    25-02-1940
1940-02-25 => zo 25-02-1940

1940-02-26 =>    26-02-1940
1940-02-26 => ma 26-02-1940
```

Instead, I get this on the production server:

```
1940-02-24 =>    24-02-1940
1940-02-24 => vr 23-02-1940

1940-02-25 =>    25-02-1940
1940-02-25 => za 24-02-1940

1940-02-26 =>    26-02-1940
1940-02-26 => ma 26-02-1940
```

How can I fix this discrepancy?

Thanks and kind regards,
Frans-Willem

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. What versions of PHP are on each system and what are the default timezones (`date_default_timezone_get()`) ?

Comment: I also would say your server has a different timezone config than your local system.

Comment: @Jim , the local development machine runs PHP 8.2.9 on Fedora 38 with `\IntlTimeZone::getTZDataVersion()` being `2022e`.
 
The production server runs PHP 8.2.8 on Debian 12 with `\IntlTimeZone::getTZDataVersion()` being `2022e`, too.

Both systems have `date_default_timezone_get()` being `UTC`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller both systems have their timezone set to `Europe/Amsterdam` on a system level. In both PHP's, `date_default_timezone_get()` returns `UTC`, see my previous comment to Jim.

Comment: @Frans-WillemPost apparently this is a bug (or maybe not?) in the newer ICU library versions which are used on some systems including Debian: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/10898 | Try the workaround suggested, use `IntlDateFormatter::formatObject()` instead of `format()` (the latter drops the date object's timezone and uses the INTL default and formatter timezones instead which might be the issue).

Comment: Maybe there is still something configured different. You could check a diff of both php -i. Also note, that php-cli and php-fpm may have also different configs.

Comment: @MarkusZeller The only relevant difference I can find from both `php -i`: Local development machine: `timelib version => 2022.09` and Server: `timelib version => 2022.07`. The Olson database versions are the same, though.